# Arrange the numbers in input name element array from zero up after remove a input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want after remove one of the rows (Ex: **Row 2**) in html code changed to in name element by jQuery.

For example we first have in html as:

> **Row 1:**  name="check[**0**][]" 
>   **Row 2(removed):**  name="check[**1**][]" 
>   **Row 3:**  name="check[**2**][]" 
>   **Row 4:**  name="check[**3**][]"

Now if we remove the second row, In fact, after removed the row 2,  we have rows like this:

> **Row 1:**  name="check[**0**][]" 
>   **Row 3:**  name="check[**2**][]" 
>   **Row 4:**  name="check[**3**][]"

But i want it in result (after remove one of rows ex: row 2) as:

> **Row 1:**  name="check[**0**][]" 
>   **Row 3:**  name="check[**1**][]" 
>   **Row 4:**  name="check[**2**][]"

I tried as (see my full code) but Don't work: http://jsfiddle.net/k3wne/

Js:

```
$('.remove_input').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).closest($class);
    remove.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('.add_units').each(function (idx, val) {
            var num = $('.add_units').length;
            NumIdx = (num - (num - idx));
            //for(var i = 0; i < num-1; i++){
            $(this).closest($class_guide).next($class_guide).each(function (idx, val) {
                $('.add_units input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name', function (idx, str) {
                    var int = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
                    return str.replace(int, NumIdx);
                })
            });
            //}
        })
    });)
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VjF9Z/)

```
$('.remove_input').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).closest('.RowCheck');
    remove.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove(); // or change next line to  $('.RowCheck:visible')
        $('.RowCheck').each(function (idx) {
            var checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]',this);
            checkBoxes.each(function(i) {
              var str = $(this).attr('name');  
              var currentIdx = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);  
              $(this).attr('name', str.replace(currentIdx,idx));
           })
        });
    });
});​
```

This code will work if you either

1. remove the row for real - also suggested by Explosion Pills **or**
2. test for visible like Simon did

Comment: ok, but my checkbox name is dynamic. it not static just `check`. How is for dynamic name?

Comment: I think I added $('.RowCheck:visible') too for only grab visible, right? Sorry but please understand I post late just as I type slow not as I'm copying answers for gain point here

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/k3wne/1/

A couple of things: You never actually remove the element once it's faded out which screws up your counts, and the last selector (`.RowCheck input[type="checkbox"]`) affects *all* checkboxes so they will all have the highest number.

In my changes, only the current row in the iteration is affected.

Answer (score 1):

Most of you code is correct, however the some changes needed:

change to use **$('.RowCheck:visible').each()**
as fadeOut is just hide that row but not really delete, and the inner loop should use **$('input[type="checkbox"]', this)**

Code looks something like following:

```
$('.remove_input').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var remove = $(this).closest('.RowCheck');
    remove.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        debugger;
        $('.RowCheck:visible').each(function (idx, val) {
            var num = $('.RowCheck:visible').length;
            NumIdx = (num - (num - idx));
            //for(var i = 0; i < num-1; i++){
            //$(this).closest('.RowCheck').next().each(function (idx, val) {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]', this).attr('name', function (idx, str) {
                    var int = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
                    return str.replace(int, NumIdx);
                })
            //});
            //}
        });
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k3wne/3/)

Comment: I think I added $('.RowCheck:visible') too for only grab visible, right? Sorry but please understand I post late just as I type slow not as I'm copying answers for gain point here

Comment: I saw this after I posted. I rechecked my answer and it does indeed renumber but renumbers all the rows, visible or not