# arrange the numbers in input name element array after remove one of it by js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I want after add a input and remove it, arrange the numbers in input name element array by jQuery but don't work for me after remove input. How can fix it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mUMdW/

My Code:

**Html:**

```
<div class="ch">
        <a href="#" class="adding">Add</a>
</div>
<p class="ffdd"></p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function removeidx(clss, type){
    var remove = $(this).closest(clss);
    remove.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove(); // or change next line to  $('.RowCheck:visible')
        $(clss).each(function (idx) {
            var checkBoxes = $('input[type="'+type+'"]',this);
            checkBoxes.each(function(i) {
              var str = $(this).attr('name');  
              var currentIdx = parseInt(str.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);  
              $(this).attr('name', str.replace(currentIdx,idx));
           })
        });
    });
}
$(document).on('click change', 'a.adding', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $('.Row').length;
    $('.ffdd').append('<div class="Row"> <input name="arr['+idx+'][]" type="text" value=""> <a href="#" class="remove_row" title="remove this row">Remove</a></div>');   
});
$('.ffdd').on('click','a', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.Row').remove();
    removeidx('.ffdd', 'text');
})
```

Comment: are you trying to get the length of the text entered in the input??

Comment: SGhosh@- no. what is it?

Comment: I suppose i didn't understand your question as in "arrange the numbers in input name element array". Could you please give an example of what you ant to do?

Comment: ok, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956001/arrange-the-numbers-in-input-name-element-array-from-zero-up-after-remove-a-inpu

Comment: So that is what you want to achieve? Something different?

Comment: Don't work function removeidx(clss, type) after remove input. what do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to re-number the inputs after a remove, so that the array is made of contiguous numbers.

I have rewritten some things, among which the renumbering function, using an index contextual to the parent function.

```
function removeidx(context, clss, type) {
    var remove = $(context).closest(clss);
    remove.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).remove();
        var idx = 0;
        $(clss).each(function () {
            var checkBoxes = $('input[type="' + type + '"]', this);
            checkBoxes.each(function () {
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                name = name.replace(/\d+/, idx);
                $(this).attr('name', name);
                idx = idx + 1;
            });
        });
    });
}

$(document).on('click change', 'a.adding', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = $('.Row').length;
    $('.ffdd').append('<div class="Row"> <input name="arr[' + idx + '][]" type="text" value=""> <a href="#" class="remove_row" title="remove this row">Remove</a></div>');
});

$('.ffdd').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    removeidx(this, '.Row', 'text');
})
```

You can see a working version there : http://jsfiddle.net/8sVWp/